# With all duly respect could you please

Tags: word-usage, word-order

"With all duly respect could you please"  is that sentence correct?

Comment: We have a handful of reasons questions get put on hold. One of them is for _proofreading_ – when someone asks if something is correct but doesn't provide a specific source of concern. Another is _insufficient details_ – when a question provides no context about where a sentence came from. This question could probably be put on hold for either reason, but I'll choose the latter, because the links in the message might be more helpful to you for future questions.

Comment: Surely this is "with all DUE respect", not DULY

Answer (score 3):

> **[duly](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/duly+respect)**
>   1. adv   If you say that something **duly happened** or **was done**, you mean that it was expected to happen or was requested, and it did happen or it was done.
>
> *Westcott appealed to Waite for an apology, which **he duly received***.

But

> **[with (all due) respect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with-all-due-respect)**
>   also with (the greatest) respect
>   ​used to express polite disagreement in a formal situation:
>
> *With **all due respect**, Sir, I cannot agree with your last statement*.

So the sentence should read: *With all due respect could you please....?*
(Don't forget the question mark!)

Comment: I'm glad you got this answer in before I put the question on hold. It's a very helpful answer, even if the question could use some improvement. Excellent work. :-)

Comment: @J.R. thank you, I considered it an example of an eggcorn, so worth pointing out the difference in meaning.